# Replace main Jar in existing Spark Job in Databricks

Tags: java, apache-spark, databricks

I'm trying to replace the task jar on an existing spark job in Databricks via the Databricks REST API or Databricks CLI (which internally uses the REST API).

I have been going through the documentation and tried the `jobs/reset` endpoint which does provide an option to change the main jar, but it is expected to be in the `job-jars` directory to which I cannot upload via the `libraries/upload` endpoint.

I have exported an existing job and the jar seems to be be assigned a dynamic name when uploaded from the UI such as:

```
"spark_jar_task": {
        "jar_uri": "2660454b_ac2a_4a60_8259_4bfeef8f23e7-MyTask_0_1.jar",
        "main_class_name": "com.mypackage.SomeTask"
}
```

So my question is, is there a way to achieve the same functionality as the  Jobs -> Upload Jar link provides via the REST API (or CLI)? I need this for Jenkins configuration.

I have read [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/04/06/continuous-integration-and-delivery-of-apache-spark-applications-at-metacog.html) article where the jar is uploaded via a python script. I would prefer to use the API if possible.